# Cannot debug config error during startup

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using springboot 1.2.7 for a new project and have a hard time finding my configuration errors during launch process. 
Each time I have an error, it doesn't display in the console, all I have is :

```
2015-11-20 14:36:38.533 ERROR 5200 --- [           main]   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

2015-11-20 14:36:38.538 ERROR 5200 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

I try to put some breakpoints but cannot find what REALLY cause this error.

In this case I got this error when I add '@Transactional' in a service ...
If I remove the @Transactional, springboot launch normally.

Got this problem for all conf problems, it makes my debugging takes ages to just find the initial error.

I'm using logback and the log level is set to DEBUG.

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the solution : I need to add -Ddebug in my tomcat launch command and it will display errors during launch process.